# Duda sobre height con tres divs

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un problema aver como puedo resolverlo.Imaginaos la siguiente cuestion:

```
<div>
  <div>Titulo</div>
  <div>Cuerpo</div>
  <div>Otro</div>
</div>
```

Bueno mi problema es el siguiente. El div *titulo* puede variar el height dependiendo del texto que tenga y si el navegador se hace mas grande o mas pequeño. El div *cuerpo* me interesa que tenga un overflow auto para el scroll y el height que se adapte entre *titulo* y *otro*.Por ultimo el div *otro* y el div padre tendrian un height fijo definido en px. Mi problema es que no consigo generar que *cuerpo* se adapte perfectamente entre *titulo* y *otro*.

Alguien me podria echar una mano.

Gracias de antemano un saludo

PD: me interesa que funcione en navegadores algo antiguos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es mi solución. Estoy utilizando flexbox y `flex-direction:column`

```css
* {
  box-size: border-box;
}

div div {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

.principal {
  height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}

div div{
width:calc(100% - 2em) 
}

div div:nth-of-type(2){flex:1 1 100%; overflow:scroll}
```

```html
<div class="principal">
  <div>Titulo</div>
  <div><h1>Cuerpo</h1>
    <p>Bueno mi problema es el siguiente. El div titulo puede variar el height dependiendo del texto que tenga y si el navegador se hace mas grande o mas pequeño. El div cuerpo me interesa que tenga un overflow auto para el scroll y el height que se adapte entre titulo y otro.Por ultimo el div otro y el div padre tendrian un height fijo definido en px. Mi problema es que no consigo generar que cuerpo se adapte perfectamente entre titulo y otro.
Alguien me podria echar una mano.
Gracias de antemano un saludo</p>
    <p>Bueno mi problema es el siguiente. El div titulo puede variar el height dependiendo del texto que tenga y si el navegador se hace mas grande o mas pequeño. El div cuerpo me interesa que tenga un overflow auto para el scroll y el height que se adapte entre titulo y otro.Por ultimo el div otro y el div padre tendrian un height fijo definido en px. Mi problema es que no consigo generar que cuerpo se adapte perfectamente entre titulo y otro.
Alguien me podria echar una mano.
Gracias de antemano un saludo</p>
    <p>Bueno mi problema es el siguiente. El div titulo puede variar el height dependiendo del texto que tenga y si el navegador se hace mas grande o mas pequeño. El div cuerpo me interesa que tenga un overflow auto para el scroll y el height que se adapte entre titulo y otro.Por ultimo el div otro y el div padre tendrian un height fijo definido en px. Mi problema es que no consigo generar que cuerpo se adapte perfectamente entre titulo y otro.
Alguien me podria echar una mano.
Gracias de antemano un saludo</p>
    <p>Bueno mi problema es el siguiente. El div titulo puede variar el height dependiendo del texto que tenga y si el navegador se hace mas grande o mas pequeño. El div cuerpo me interesa que tenga un overflow auto para el scroll y el height que se adapte entre titulo y otro.Por ultimo el div otro y el div padre tendrian un height fijo definido en px. Mi problema es que no consigo generar que cuerpo se adapte perfectamente entre titulo y otro.
Alguien me podria echar una mano.
Gracias de antemano un saludo</p>
  </div>
  <div>Otro</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta solucion me daria problemas en IE

Comment: Flexbox funciona en IE 10 y 11. Este ejemplo también

Comment: width:calc(100% - 2em)  funciona?

Comment: Lo he probado en IE y funciona. Porque no lo abres en IE para ver? https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: gracias, lo preguntaba porque en el momento que escribi el comentario utilizaba un ordenador con opensuse.

Answer (score 0):

Trabaja con porcentajes el titulo y el cuerpo
ej:

```
height:20%;
```

y el otro div podrias ponerlo de varia maneras 
podrias ponerlo afuera de los divs y abajo del div padre, asi daria la misma sensacion o darle le height a partir de javascript, aqui un pseudocodigo de como podria ser.

```
height = {divPadreHeight} - ({TituloHeight} + {CuerpoHeight})
```

Comment: El problema es que el titulo height aveces puede necesitar un 1% del height y otras el 30 dependiendo del texto que recupere de la bbdd

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar flex para que el div central se expanda:

```html
    <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:200px;">
      <div>Titulo</div>
      <div style="flex-grow:1;background:yellow">Cuerpo</div>
      <div>Otro</div>
    </div>
```

Nota que tendrías que darle una altura al `div` exterior.

Comment: y esto seria compatible con opera, safari y las ultimas versiones de IE??

Comment: Según dice aquí: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox, soporte en IE 11 es parcial pero el ejemplo que he puesto debería funcionar (mírate las "known issues"). Para el resto de navegadores sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer uso de grid css, donde al div padre le indicas con 'display: grid', que sus hijos seran distribuidos usando la especificacion grid, como esta en fila entonces se usa 'grid-auto-flow: row;', y con 'grid-template-rows: minmax(10%,20%) auto 40px;', se le indica como se distribuiran los tres div's, el primero con un minimo de 10% y 20% del height padre, el segundo sera auto, lo q indica q su div se calcula de acuerdo al restante del padre, y el tercero es fijo.

```css
.class1 {
    height: 150px;
    display: grid;  
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(10%,20%) auto 40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 5px solid blue;" class="class1">
  <div style="border: 5px solid green;">Titulo</div>
  <div style="border: 5px solid yellow;">Cuerpo</div>
  <div style=" border: 1px solid red;">Otro</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ya intente una solucion similar pero no es compatible con IE